# Symfony duplicate route name issue for overridden controllers

Tags: symfony

I came across a strange issue with my Symfony controllers.

I have 2 classes `UserController` and `ClientUserController`.

And `ClientUserController extends UserController`. I have overidden a controller method in the `ClientUserController`.

I have this route in my `ClientUserController`.

```
@Route("/user/get-requirements/{userId}", name="client_user_get_requirements")
```

And I have this route in my `UserController`.

```
@Route("/user/get-requirements/{userId}", name="user_get_requirements")
```

The problem here is when I access this URL `/user/get-requirements/33` this completely ignores the `ClientUserController`'s overridden method and runs the original method in `UserController`.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing some config?

Comment: Symfony initialises both controllers. How also depends on the service configuration. But that does not matter. Therefore you have two actions with one and the same route.  Even if both route attributes have a different name, the route that was initialised first always wins. https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/routing.html#debugging-routes

Comment: Is there a ways to fix it or get around it?

Comment: You have exactly two identical route definitions in your application. It's like having the same URI twice. It is technically impossible for the same URI to exist twice. So Symfony decides to use one route definition. The solution is: you are not allowed to extend the controller and have to define two different routes. Attributes are also inherited when extending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer with some help. It seems like, Symfony does override controller function only if the route names are exactly the same, not the URLs.

I had to change the `ClientUserController`'s route name to

```
@Route("/user/get-requirements/{userId}", name="user_get_requirements")
```

Seems like the route name gets overridden and this did the trick.

Answer (score -1):

On Symfony >=5.1 you can use `priority` on routes.

`@Route("/user/get-requirements/{userId}", name="client_user_get_requirements", priority=10)`

(Default `priority` is 0)

see https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-1-route-annotations-priority